# Angular - uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'totalQuestions' of undefined

Tags: angular, typeerror

I'm trying to group quiz properties together as a quizMetadata object and then use object, but getting this error: "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'totalQuestions' of undefined"

```
export class ResultsComponent implements OnInit {
  quizData: Quiz = QUIZ_DATA;
  quizMetadata: {
    totalQuestions: number;
    correctAnswersCount$: Observable<number>;
    percentage: number;
    completionTime: number;
  };

...
constructor(private quizService: QuizService) {
  this.quizMetadata.totalQuestions = this.quizService.numberOfQuestions();
  ...
}
```

Comment: You need to initialize `quizMetadata` with some value. As it stands, it is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna `subscribe` your Service

```
export class SomeComponent {

  currentValue: string;

  constructor(private someService: SomeService) {
    someService.getSomeObservable().subscribe(result => {
      this.currentValue = result ;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your quizMetadata is not correctly affected with the initial value. Instead of:

```js
quizMetadata: {
    totalQuestions: number;
    correctAnswersCount$: Observable<number>;
    percentage: number;
    completionTime: number;
  };
```

Do like this:

```js
quizMetadata = {
    totalQuestions: number;
    correctAnswersCount$: Observable<number>;
    percentage: number;
    completionTime: number;
  };
```

Comment: I mean use = instead of : when initializing quizMetadata

Comment: I tried this but am getting red squiggly lines underneath the types.

Comment: As quizMetadata is not typed, it is not a problem (Probably you have activated strict type checking in your editor). Otherwise you should type quizMetadata and do like quizMetadata : <Its type> = { your initial value }, just like what you have done with quizData

Comment: Okay I will try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make all the properties optional and initialize with the empty object

```js
quizMetadata: {
    totalQuestions: number;
    correctAnswersCount$: Observable<number>;
    percentage: number;
    completionTime: number;
};
```

To

```js
quizMetadata: {
    totalQuestions ?: number;
    correctAnswersCount$ ?: Observable<number>;
    percentage ?: number;
    completionTime ?: number;
} = {};
```

Comment: tried using: quizMetadata: QuizMetadata = {
    totalQuestions?: number,
    correctAnswersCount$?: Observable<number>,
    percentage?: number,
    completionTime?: number
  } = {}; but am getting red squiggly lines for the fields and error TS1109: Expression expected. for the line with the Observable

Comment: quizMetadata: QuizMetadata = { totalQuestions?: number, correctAnswersCount$?: Observable<number>, percentage?: number, completionTime?: number } = {};

It's Wrong Intialization it's getting two times intialized check that
Correct Initialization: 
```javascript
quizMetadata: {totalQuestions ?: number;correctAnswersCount$ ?: Observable<number>;percentage ?: number;completionTime ?: number;} = {};
```
If you want to use Interface for that make the properties in the interface optional with '?' this.
and initialized like the following
```javascript
quizMetadata: QuizMetadata = {};
```